# Combinations in Arrays

Tags: arrays, for-loop, combinations

I have two 1D arrays -or vectors- corresponding to coordinates X and Y

eg. `X = [1,2,3] ,  Y = [a,b,c]`

I'd like to mix each X individually with all Y individually in a two column array:

eg. `XY = [1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3a, 3b, 3c]`

Keep in mind that it's not a product of `1*a,1*b`; they are coordinates have to be kept separately

I hope that I explained myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below :

```
    int X[] = {1,2,3};
    int Y[] = {1,2,3};
    int XY[][] = new int[X.length*Y.length][2];
    for(int i=0;i<X.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<Y.length;j++){
            XY[i*Y.length+j][0] = X[i];
            XY[i*Y.length+j][1] = Y[j];
        }
    }
```